# Sort column in dependence of another column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I try to sort one column after another. In doing so, I deliberately create duplicates.

This is what my df looks like at the moment:

```
      ticket  magic      Id
0  193454845  1311     1313
1  193454846  1927     1311
2  193454847  1810     1927
3  193454852  1313     NaN
```

What I want:

```
      ticket  magic      Id
0  193454845  1311     1311
1  193454846  1927     1927
2  193454847  1810     NaN
3  193454852  1313     1313
```

The column "magic" and "Id" should be identical if no NaN.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Some more context might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the value in the `id` column for `magic = 1313` should be `NaN` instead.

```
data['id'] = np.where(data['Id'].isna(), np.nan, data['magic'])
```

Update:

```
data.merge(data[['Id']], left_on='magic', right_on='Id', how='left',suffixes=['_x','']).drop(columns='Id_x')

    ticket      magic   Id
0   193454845   1311    1311.0
1   193454846   1927    1927.0
2   193454847   1810    NaN
3   193454852   1313    1313.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but that's not what I mean.

I would like the column "Id" sorted by the column "magic". So "Id" and "magic" should be the same. The "NaN" should be where there is no value in "Id" for "magic", like in the code above.

Comment: I'd use a  `left join` to get that. See my updated answer.